# How to set an image in surface view and how to erase it

Tags: android

I am working on an app in which i need to set an image when app starts, and then user can erase that image to look covered image under erasable image. I am new in android, please help.

Comment: i answered you yesterday, why dont you read your own questions?

Comment: @pskink i dint get you yesterday, i am looking for a little description.